# My core class My_head not found in codeigniter

Tags: php, class, codeigniter

I am trying to create core class in codeigniter. In application/core I create a file with the name of MY_head.php and the code of MY_head.php is:

```
class MY_head extends CI_Controller{
 
  public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
  }
 
  public function load_header(){
      //some code here
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to extend this class in my controller practice.php the code is:

```
class Practice extends MY_head{
   public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
   }

   function index(){
   }
}
```

But when I load the practice controller in the browser it says

> Fatal error: Class 'MY_head' not found in.

Where is the problem?

Note : $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting below function at the bottom of config file

**/application/config/config.php**

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . '.php' );
    }
}
```

and Extend Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Practice extends MY_head
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

**OR include manually**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// include the base class
require_once("application/core/MY_head.php");

//Extend the class 
class Practice extends MY_head
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Why do i need to include this class ? does codeigniter doesn't load the core classes automatically ?

Comment: only MY_Controller.php core class is auto loading but not the other classes. what can be the reason ?

Comment: @AkshayHegde has the correct answer. (use the `function __autoload($class)...`.  The reason is CodeIgniter allows you to overload core classes **with the same name**.   IE: `MY_Controller` but not `MY_Head`.  To autoload classes of a certain type you must autoload them outside of CI's standard way.

Comment: i put the following code in config.php but the error still same.....function __autoload($class)
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }
}

Comment: Could be constant is not defined. Try with: `APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . '.php'`.

Comment: @Tpojka yes there is chance

Comment: Edit yor answer and replace EXE with '.php' so i can accept it as correct one

Comment: @AliciaDsney : actually if you define constant `EXE` in index.php, it will work, but as you said, I edited

Comment: how to define in index.php ?

Comment: @AliciaDsney : codeigniter main folder there will be `index.php` there you can define constant `define('EXE', '.php');` or else you can define in `application/config/constants.php`
`

Comment: @Akhsay another question for you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642379/codeigniter-controller-is-not-working

Answer (score 5):

`function __autoload($class)` is deprecated:

Update for PHP 7.x and up

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . '.php' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe don't want to include it manually or modify CI system each time you make a core class. You only need to change your class name case in order for CI to read it. For example `MY_Head` or `MY_Head_Controller`. Those are the class name format should be.
So your core class name should be like

```
class MY_Head extends CI_Controller{

 public function __construct(){

     parent::__construct();
     }

     public function load_header(){
        //some code here
     }
 }
```

and call it like

```
class Practice extends MY_Head
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

I tried that and works.

**Note.**
The file name must be `MY_Controller.php` if your class prefix is `MY_` and you extend `CI_Controller`.