# Codeigniter Controller is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I am new in codeigniter and bit confused My conditioner is not pickup my Controller, My controller practice.php and code is:

```
class Practice extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function foo()
    {
        echo 'Hello world';
    }
    function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello index';
    }
}
```

I am trying to load it like Localhost/foldername/practice/foo . its suppose to work why not?

Thanks.

Note : Practice is also my default controller without contoller name index function is working like localhost/foldername/ will show the index function result.

Comment: why you need foldername ?

Comment: pr is the folder in which codeigniter is so off course i need this folder name in address bar.

Comment: localhost/foldername/index.php/practice/foo and rename practice.php file to Practice.php

Comment: If you use .htaccess file then you can avoid index.php from url

Comment: controller file first latter suppose to be big ?

Comment: Yes, first char should be in uppercase

Comment: Thanks its working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter says:

> By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:
>
> > example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article

Try to access it using this one

```
localhost/foldername/index.php/practice/foo
```

If you want to access it without the index.php, you should create a .htaccess file in your root directory and place this code:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteBase /foldername/
# If your project is in server root then should be: RewriteBase /
# If your project is in folder then it should be: RewriteBase /foldername/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

See [CodeIgniter URLs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)