# Extending CodeIgniter core classes

Tags: codeigniter, inheritance, codeigniter-3

I have in my core folder, 2 controllers:

1. MY_Controller
2. MY_AdminController

Both extend CI_Controller. First one works great, but second one no, when I call the controller which is inheriting from MY_AdminController I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_AdminController' not found
```

After doing some research I found:

```
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
```

In this document it says you use "MY_" prefix (possible to change it in config) to extend core classes, I am doing that.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I am wondering if the problem is because since I am creating a file inside "core" folder, CI checks if it does exist an original on its own core with same name but prefix CI?

Comment: Make sure your filename matches the class application core/MY_Admincontroller.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question, it was a typo, on my code I have the same as class name an file name

Comment: There is no CI_Admincontroller, so you can't extend something that's not there.

Comment: I am extending CI_Controller @BrianGottier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342232/extending-the-controller-class-in-codeigniter) as to why you can't do it the way you have described. Essentially CodeIgniter looks for `['subclass_prefix'] . $Classname`, e.g. `'MY_' . 'Controller'`. And here is the same question for [CI2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627587/code-igniter-2-how-to-extend-ci-controller-multiple-times)

**Solution:**
Put both `MY_Controller` and `MY_AdminController` in `MY_Controller.php`

*MY_Controller.php*

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    ...
}

class MY_AdminController extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I will try that. Not including the class on the same file, but using a require inside it, I like to keep controllers files visible.

Comment: Good idea, one class per file is preferable

Comment: I posted another question, maybe you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368601/loading-view-inside-a-library-issues-with-cached-vars

Answer (score 2):

to allow any new class . means **which class are note defined in system/core** 
solution could be as follow.

> Try putting below function at the bottom of config file

```
/application/config/config.php

function __autoload($class) {
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . '.php' );
    } }
```

[My core class My_head not found in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620013/my-core-class-my-head-not-found-in-codeigniter)