# Loading view inside a Library, issues with cached vars

Tags: codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-3, loadview

I am trying to implement a widgets library using load->view. I know I can use include to call directly the file and avoid the vars cache issues but just wondering why it does not work.

Here is how I have structured my code:

My Controller:

```
class Page extends MY_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        ...
        $this->load->library('widgetmanager');
    }

    public function index($slug = '') {

        echo $this->widgetmanager->show(2);
        echo $this->widgetmanager->show(1);

    }
}
```

My Library

```
class WidgetManager
{

    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
    }

    public function show($widget_id) {
        $data = array();
        $widget_id = (int)$widget_id;



        $this->CI->db->select('*');
        $this->CI->db->from('widget');
        $this->CI->db->where('id', $widget_id);

        $query = $this->CI->db->get();

        $item = $query->row_array();

        $data['widget_title'] = $item['title'];
        $data['widget_content'] = $item['content'];

        $widget =  $this->CI->load->view('widget/'.$item['source'], $data, TRUE);

        $data['widget_title'] = '';
        $data['widget_content'] = '';

        $this->CI->load->view('widget/'.$item['source'], $data);

        return $widget;
    }
}
```

widget 1: Calls widget/content
widget 2: Calls widget/banner

What is happening is, the vars set on the first widget call (they are same name as second widget call), get cached, meaning values from the first call are passed to same call. It is weird because are different views.

I have tried:

- Using clear_vars(): $this->CI->load->clear_vars(), before and after doing load->view on the library.
- Calling load->view with empty array, null, etc
- Tried to add a prefix with the widget slug to the vars (that works, but I have to send in some way the prefix to the view, so it is not possible due cache issue)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you load the view twice in the `show()` method?

Comment: @DFriend it is a method to build a widget, I am calling 2 different widgets

Comment: Yes, but you load the same view twice in the `show()` method.

Comment: @DFriend it is not the same, source defines which one, it is dynamic

Comment: Not the way you have it coded. Inside the function `show` both calls to `load->view` use the same file as defined by `$item['source']`.

Comment: @DFriend the second call in the show method was intended to do something similar than clear_vars. Something similar to what you did in your second suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here is what should work.

(I took the liberty of simplifying your database call making it require much less processing.)

```
public function show($widget_id)
{
    $data = array();
    $widget_id = (int) $widget_id;

    $item = $this->CI->db
      ->get_where('widget', array('id' => $widget_id))
      ->row_array();

    $data['widget_title'] = $item['title'];
    $data['widget_content'] = $item['content'];

    $widget = $this->CI->load->view('widget/'.$item['source'], $data, TRUE);

    //clear the cached variables so the next call to 'show()' is clean
    $this->CI->load->clear_vars(); 

    return $widget;
}
```

On further consideration The call `$this->CI->load->clear_vars();` is probably pointless because each time `WidgetManager::show()` is called the `$data` var is recreated with exactly the same keys. When the $data var is passed to `load->view` the new values of $data['widget_title'] and $data['widget_content'] will replace the values in the cached vars using those keys.

Comment: just tried, unfortunately it does not work, it keeps happening the same.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the problem. You show two different widgets (different titles and content). But what get displayed is the same widget content twice?

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to help me. I have a folder called "widget" inside "views" folder. Inside of it, I have different files, in example: content, banner, steps. Content is my general widget, used for most cases. I am looking to load the content processed of those widgets to then load them to my page through action page/index in my controller.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help. I think I understand what your goal is. I am trying to understand exactly what gets displayed differs from what you expect.

Comment: On the first call, the variables: $widget_title and $widget_content have the values expected, in the second call, those same vars, still have the values from the first call.

Comment: I tested the revised answer above. The only reason I can think of that you see the same title and content is if the database records are the same.

Comment: No, they are different. I am running version 3.0.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155127/discussion-between-dfriend-and-eduardo).

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue here and for debug purpose you can check the cached variables by CI load with this method:

```
$this->CI->load->get_vars();
```

It's useful to use after call Load method to know the cached vars. If you need clean this "cache" you can use the method exposed by @DFriend :

```
$this->CI->load->clear_vars();
```

If you don't wanna call this method, and take adventage of the cache, you can rewrite the variables.